# How can I change my user ID in the profile URL?

Tags: support, users, display-names

How can I change the userid in my profile URL?

At the moment, I can only change my public user name, but there is no way to change the userid shown in the URL.

There should be a way to change the userId in the profile URL too for complete anonymity if someone wants to change the URL. At the moment, we can only change the username towards the end of the profile URL... which is not really a good way to remain anonymous if someone already has your profile link.

Comment: Are you talking about the *numerical* ID? No, that cannot be changed. It uniquely identifies your account, and is what enables your name to be changed at will (and to be non-unique). If you want to anonymize your profile, that's a different request, for which you can [contact the team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) to have your account permanently deleted and thus all of your content become owned by an anonymous user.

Comment: Sorry, I researched for similar question in stackoverflow for one hr. And could not find even a similar question asked by others. So thats why I put the question here. And can you pls share the URL that provides this details about the restriction in changing the User ID ?

Comment: @Kent I'm not the downvoter (in fact, I haven't voted yet), but I can think a possibility that "change user ID in profile URL" doesn't make sense, thus the downvote. Anyway, in case you aren't used to meta, consider reading [What's Meta?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) first. Also, votes don't really mean anything here, so you can just ignore it.

Comment: Stack would only look as if it's imitating Facebook etc. So, a custom url / id *huh?*

Comment: _"I want to post in a public forum but I want to do it anonymously"_... that's not how it works I'm afraid.

Comment: This looks like the classic mistake of asking about a perceived solution but not describing the problem.  In case it needs to be mentioned, there are already a lot of meta questions about serial downvotes.

Comment: ""I want to post in a public forum but I want to do it anonymously"... that's not how it works I'm afraid. " Is your second name Facebook or Google? It's a right to post to a public forum with some kind of anonymity.

Comment: Not only the numeric ID can't be changed, the first name you entered when creating the profile. I couldn't change it.

Answer (score 23):

You can't change your userid nor can you change your [network id, Andy](https://stackexchange.com/users/2986549).

The userid, and as a matter of fact all primary keys, are generated by the SQL Server database engine (they are defined as [`IDENTITY(1,1)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)<sup>1</sup>) so there is no SE code at the moment involved by picking that number. Making it possible to select your userid would require quite some UX and code changes with only marginal benefits.

I personally don't see how privacy could be a reason to change the id. Changing your userid would render links that visitors collected indeed useless, but as I assume you want to keep your posts the new userid would be revealed when anyone visits your posts. And I'm pretty sure most users will find your profile due to your post, so having a new userid will not change that, at all.

If you still think going the extra mile to have a different userid, you could create a new account but you can't merge it with your current profile as new accounts are merged into the older one, [as stated by @Animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358601/how-can-i-change-my-user-id-in-the-profile-url/358602?noredirect=1#comment526943_358602). So you would have to start all over.

If you're worried that certain posts reveal your identity you can flag the post and request disassociation from them. This will remove your userid from the post but as a consequence you will also no longer have any reputation from that post. Remember that there could still be references to your old profile name in comments and post notices. Outside of SE users can use the [Wayback Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine) to find the OP.

If being anonymous is important to you, either build and use a virtual identity that has no ties with your real identity or don't sign-up on sites that have user profiles in the first place. Alternatively you might like *[Need to ask a question anonymously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/need-to-ask-a-question-anonymously)*, but that doesn't doesn't help for your current profile.

---

<sup>1. [Confirmed by Adam Lear](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6454884#6454884)</sup>

Comment: Merging is not a solution here. We always merge into the lower user ID. You can't get a new one in this way.

Comment: "I personally don't see how privacy could be a reason to change the id. Changing your userid would render links that visitors..." It can be a matter of privacy, if the user made a mistake in the name, realizing later that the name is linked to something else they don't want to link. Tracing and linking activities is the definition of lack of privacy. So, I can understand how it can be privacy related in some cases.

Comment: @Quidam well ... this is a public service and from the start it is made clear that anything you do here is in the open. I have a hard time to link a users mishap to a privacy concern. It is more a taking responsibility issue and certainly not a concern for the service provider, let alone a privacy issue as defined/regulated by law.

Comment: So, why you don't post your full name? American people and firms have a lot of problem to understand what is privacy. By the way, it's not a "public service".

Comment: @Quidam I'm not american, please don't insult me as such. Let's agree it is a "free" service and call it a day.