# How do I prevent SO from forwarding an old link to my profile to my new one?

Tags: support, profile-page

https://stackoverflow.com/users/70553/xxx-yyyzzz

A link to my SO profile with my old username (redacted since it had my actual name) still forwards to my current SO profile:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/70553/miso-soup

This is an issue for me since Google and other search engines show this as the 2nd result of searches for my name. Seemingly, the only way to correct this issue it to change my SO account# from 70553 to a new number -or- to delete my account entirely.

Is anyone familiar with a solution to this problem? I don't want to delete my SO account, but I see no other way to fix this.

Comment: If some place on the internet has a link to your profile along with text that you don't want associated with it then you need to find that place and correct it.  If it's on SO, you can edit the posts to use the updated link, if it's not, then it's that other place that you have a problem with, not SO, so there isn't anything for SO to do.

Comment: You can't. Stack Overflow only cares about the *id in the URL*, not whatever comes after. It then redirects the browser to the current canonical name.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358601/how-can-i-change-my-user-id-in-the-profile-url/358602#358602

Comment: And Google is not the only record of your name in the URL. Stack Overflow is archived all over the internet, and even without the redirect people *will* find your new account name, as it is the *id number* that matters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/Hitler-Did-Nothing-Wrong is definitely NOT me.

Comment: Your job is "on top at her"? How funny. Not.

Answer (score 9):

You don't. The name is irrelevant; your user ID is what identifies your profile; you could be https://stackoverflow.com/users/70553/definitely-not-miso-soup if you wanted to be.

Eventually, Google will crawl enough pages to make this less of an issue. Of course, there'll still be caches, scrapers, old data-dumps... Just can't reliably delete stuff from the internet.

Comment: Instead of OP deleting his account can't SO resolve his specific issue and change his account id?

Comment: *Maybe,* @Oleg; that's kinda iffy and won't necessarily do what they want. But, they can /contact us via the link at the bottom of the page & we can look into it. No promises.